# Scaling issue in a RadioButton with text

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

Please have a look at the following code

**input.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main" >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/logo_image"
        android:background="@drawable/background_green"
        android:src="@drawable/titleimage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:stretchColumns="*" >

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/device_type_row"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/device_type_radio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:text="@string/device_type" />

                <RadioGroup 
                    android:id="@+id/device_type_radio_selection"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioIos"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/iOS"
                        />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioAndroid"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/android"
                        />


                </RadioGroup>


            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/days_as_customers_row"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/days_as_customers_radio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/days_as_customers" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:weightSum="2" >

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/days_as_customer_seekbar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/days_as_customer_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1/210"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/input_submit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/submit_button_img" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Basically, this gives the following UI

[image]

Now the problem is, the `RadioButtons` with text in the first column of the table takes only 40% of the available width. But, I need them to take 75% of the available width, and the things in second column can get the rest.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background_main" >

    <ImageView 
         android:id="@+id/logo_image"
    android:background="@drawable/background_green"
    android:src="@drawable/titleimage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/logo_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/device_type_row"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/device_type_radio"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/device_type" />

                <RadioGroup 
                    android:id="@+id/device_type_radio_selection"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioIos"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/iOS"
                        />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/radioAndroid"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="@string/android"
                        />


                </RadioGroup>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/days_as_customers_row"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/days_as_customers_radio"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.75"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/days_as_customers" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.25">

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/days_as_customer_seekbar"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/days_as_customer_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1/210"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/input_submit_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@drawable/submit_button_img" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/logo"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. But why the text is not expanding, eventhough the assigned space get expanded?

Comment: @FlowOverStack you need only the text need to expand 75% .